# How to add data to a hash reference

Tags: perl

I am having issues appending data to an array of hashes.  Instead of appendibg the data into the hash it is creating a new hash.

```
$json_data = 
{
    'site_data' =>
     {
        'urldata' =>
        [
            {
                'URL' => "$filedata{'filename'}"
            }
        ],
    }
}
my %format =('Format'=>'ZIP');
push ($json_data->{'site_data'}->{'urldata'},\%format);
```

What I am expecting is.

```
'urldata':
 [
    {
        'URL':"www.espn.com",
        'Format':"ZIP"
    }

 ],
```

What I am getting is.

```
'urldata':
 [
    {
        'URL':"www.espn.com"
    },
    {
        'Format':"ZIP"
    }

 ],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

Firstly, this syntax causes problems:

```
push ($json_data->{'site_data'}->{'urldata'},\%format);
```

This uses an experimental feature that was added in Perl 5.14 and removed again in 5.24. So please don't use that. You need to explicitly deference your array reference (by putting `@{ ... }` around the expression.

```
push (@{ $json_data->{'site_data'}->{'urldata'} }, \%format);
```

But that doesn't get you any closer. That just gets you the same, broken, solution working on any version of Perl :-)

The `push()` function only works on arrays. In your case, you're using it on the array (reference) stored in the `urldata` key of your hash. But you don't want to `push()` a new element onto that array (as that gives you the incorrect result that you're currently seeing). You want to access the existing, first hash that's stored in the array and add a key/value pair to that.

The first element of your `urldata` array is given by:

```
$json_data->{'site_data'}->{'urldata'}->[0]; # The '0' gives the first element.
```

That is a hash reference, so you can add values to the hash in exactly the same way as you would for any other hash reference.

```
$json_data->{'site_data'}->{'urldata'}->[0]->{'Format'} = 'ZIP';
```

Of course, you can tidy up this code by removing the quote marks around hash keys:

```
$json_data->{site_data}->{urldata}->[0]->{Format} = 'ZIP';
```

And arrows between indexing brackets are always optional:

```
$json_data->{site_data}{urldata}[0]{Format} = 'ZIP';
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.  I was trying that, but I was pushing and that wasn't working.  I use quote marks because for whatever reason I will get errors sometimes if I don't use them.

Comment: @user3525290 The rule about quoting hash keys is the same as the rule for subroutine names and quoting before the fat comma `=>`. You don't have to quote any valid identifier, which is a bareword consisting of only letters, digits, and underscore, and not starting with a digit (unicode letters and digits are valid with `use utf8`). If it contains any other characters, it will need to be quoted.